# How to modify a specific element of a nested object using ES6?

Tags: javascript, object, react-native, ecmascript-6, redux

I have this initialStore:

```
const initialState =
{
  0:{
    screen_name: '1',
    props: null,
  },
  1:{
    screen_name: '2',
    props: null,
  },
  2:{
    screen_name: '3',
    props: null,
  },
  3:{
    screen_name: '4',
    props: null,
  },
  4:{
    screen_name: '5',
    props: null,
  },
}
```

I want to know how can I modify for example the value `state.0.screen_name: 1`, while keeping the rest of the original state using ES6?

This is the approach that I have so far:

```
export const navigationReducer = createReducer(initialState, {
  [types.CHANGE_SCREEN_EXPERIMENTAL](state,action){
    return{...state[action.id], screen_name:action.screen_name, ...state
  };
}
```

},
);

However, that returns this:

[image: result of the code above]

The `action.id` is `0`, it should modify the `state[0]` element, however, it copied its elements, modified them and placed them on the state object itself instead of the `state[0]` object.

Desired result:

```
navigationReducer:{
  0: {
     props: null,
     screen_name: "ad"
  }
  1:Object
  2:Object
  3:Object
  4:Object
}
```

I **do not** want the `screen_name` nor `props` to be outside those objects (0,1,2,3,4).

Any ideas are well appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to change? How the desired result looks like?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I will edit the answer.

Comment: In summary, I want whatever is outside the numerated `objects (0,1,2,3,4)` inside the respective `object`, I have a variable (`action.id`) that tells me which `object` should be modified. I am just missing the syntax

Comment: `object.id` is the index of the sub-object you want to change???

Comment: `action.id` is the index of the sub-object I want to change.

Comment: It's easy then just use this: `initialState[action.id].screen_name = "the new screen name you want";`! In one line!

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, I asked to do it in ES6 since I am using redux and I want to follow the syntax of my other reducers. Your result is exactly what I am looking for, but I want it to be done like the code I put in my question. I am talking about the function that starts like this `export const navigationReducer = createReducer(initialState, {...`
The reason for this is that `initialState` is just the template. Its result (a `state`) will be changed multiple times, therefore, I want to use the `{...state }` syntax but with small modifications like the one in your previous code.

Comment: Seems a little bit like you're overcomplicating things. Can't change the object before calling `export const ...`?

Comment: I can't because the object I want to change is being given to `export const navigationReducer` as a parameter `(state)` as well as the result of what I want it to be (`action.screen_name`).

Comment: The [ES6 Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) is what I am hoping to use to get my desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to do it using ES6

Here is how:

```
export const navigationReducer = createReducer(initialState, {
    [types.CHANGE_SCREEN_EXPERIMENTAL](state,action){
      return{
        ...state,[action.id]:{
          ...state[action.id],
          screen_name:action.screen_name,
          props:action.props,
        }
      };
    }
  },
);
```

This results in:

[image: result of code above]

Thank you very much for your help and time @ibrahimmahrir.